# MediaPlayer управление с гарнитуры

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Подскажите пожалуйста как считать состояние кнопки гарнитуры? Хочу с помощью нее управлять плеером.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй обрабатывать событие `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`